# How to make an application in Websphere application server available over LAN

Tags: websphere, virtual-machine, rhel, application-server, master-data-management

I have installed IBM MDM CE v11.4 on linux (RHEL v7.2) Guest in VMWare workstation the Host OS is Windows 10.

I can access the MDM console on my guest at localhost:7507, or IP:7505

I would like to access this console from my Host Operating system, the VM is using NAT adapter for networking and the result of ifconfig is

```
ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.124.131  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.124.255
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fec9:465  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:0c:29:c9:04:65  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 252  bytes 16106 (15.7 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 46  bytes 6212 (6.0 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 2683  bytes 1255131 (1.1 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 2683  bytes 1255131 (1.1 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
    ether 52:54:00:ac:d8:f5  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

from my host I can ping the IP at 192.168.124.131 but cannot access the console at 192.168.124.131:7507.

I have tried port forwarding but failed.

Please help me solve my problem. i am new to linux and networking..

Comment: I'll start by saying I don't know Windows 10 at all. However, I would bet that Microsoft enables their firewall by default. https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+10+firewall&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: And I didn't mean to finish the comment there. So try to set up the Windows firewall to allow access to port 7507.

Comment: My bad Alexander actually my host is windows 10. Updated my question according.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre your answer was suggestion was correct only I had to allow access to port 7507 on RHEL and not on windows.

Comment: I'm glad that helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Actually the port 7507 on linux guest was closed, and using iptables to open it did not work, to Open a port on RHEL v7.2 run this command to open a port

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=8080/tcp
```

then to restart

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Thats it now I can connect to my mdm server on guest from IE on my host machine.